# Semantic MediaWiki > Special:SMWAdmin > Data repair and upgrade versus rebuildData.php

Tags: semantic-mediawiki

So Special:SMWAdmin > "Data repair and upgrade" ["offers a feature to restore all Semantic MediaWiki data based on the current contents of the wiki"](https://semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Repairing_SMW%27s_data#Using_Special:SMWAdmin). Where rebuildData.php ["recreates all the semantic data in the database"](https://semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:RebuildData.php).

What exactly is the difference (besides working command line or not)? Is there any difference? Or just calls Special:SMWAdmin the rebuildData.php script?

We're using SMW 2.2.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure so I'll put it here instead of as an answer. It seems to me they do the same thing, but `SMW_refreshData.php` runs all the refresh operations immediately whereas the function from the "Data repair and upgrade" adds the tasks to MediaWiki's job queue to be carried out progressively.

Comment: You might want to discuss this at https://semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help_talk:Repairing_SMW%27s_data. Not all SMW developers are on stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The essential difference is that Special:SMWAdmin only ''queues'' the updates in the [job queue](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Job_queue), while `rebuildData.php` actually *performs* the updates.

If your job queue is correctly configured, the difference may be trivial; otherwise you'll run into [performance issues](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Job_queue#Performance_issue). A common error is to [have insufficient memory](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T60969) for the job runner. If all else fails, the last resort is [null-editing all the pages](https://github.com/SemanticMediaWiki/SemanticMediaWiki/issues/184#issuecomment-34790596).

The difference was actually written in the help page, but in a weird English; [fixed that too](https://semantic-mediawiki.org/w/index.php?title=Help%3ARebuildData.php&diff=39897&oldid=39582).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!